# Error when inserting data in ssms through "Execute Stored Procedure"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The below shown is my program:

[image]

As You can see, all the table details are correct. But when I try to run it through the "Execute Stored Procedure", the details are not entered into the table.

Rather I get a output like this:

[image]

How I can solve this?

Note: Recently had MSDB in SUSPECT, so, took my friends MSDB log and data, is that causing the problem? If yes, what can i do about that?

Comment: It's a lot easier to solve problems if you don't throw away the error messages in [try-catch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx). Look into error_message()

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: inside your catch block use the throw command instead the variable "@msg"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message would certainly help. A quick, easy change would be to replace 
set @msg='Error'
with
set @msg= ERROR_MESSAGE();
so we can see the error.

If this isn't possible I suggest:

1. Run the INSERT statement manually to see what message you get
2. Check that the ID column is an Identity column as you don't provide the ID in the INSERT so I assume it should be

I hope this helps.

Comment: You are great mate!
I forgot to do the second option you said. That is why it happened.